# Tiktok embed video CORB issue in VUE js

Tags: vue.js, cross-origin-read-blocking

This HTML works fine and the TikTok video showed perfectly (simple index.html file). But the problem is when I used this code in VUE js it gives me a CORS error

[image: cors]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js"></script> 
</head>

<blockquote class="tiktok-embed" cite="https://www.tiktok.com/@zachking/video/6904661755687865605"
    data-video-id="6904661755687865605" style="max-width: 605px;min-width: 325px;">
    <section> <a target="_blank" title="@zachking" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@zachking">@zachking</a>
        <p>What’s the longest amount of time you’ve been stuck in <a title="traffic" target="_blank"
                href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/traffic">#traffic</a> ? �</p> <a target="_blank"
            title="♬ original sound - Zach King" href="https://www.t
    k.com/music/original-sound-6904661761874479877">♬ original sound - Zach King</a>
    </section>
</blockquote>
<video></video>
</html>
```

I placed this script tag in the index.html file of vue in the head section

```
<script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js"></script>
```

I don't know why it gives CORS error. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this code worked fine.

```
// In the template of the Vue file

<iframe :src="videoUrl" :srcdoc="embedHtml"></iframe>
```

`<script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js"></script>`  in the head tag of index.html was unnecessary.